# Type conversion using 'as' in dart

Tags: dart

Why does it break in `Foo` when passing an instance of `D2` rather than setting `d1` to `null`? In .NET, it's advisable to use `as` instead of `is` because `is` normally requires **two** cast/conversion which is more expensive than `null` testing.

```
class Base {}
class D1 extends Base{}
class D2 extends Base{}

void Foo(Base d1OrD2) {
  var d1 = d1OrD2 as D1;
  if (d1 != null) print("it's d1");
  else {
    var d2 = d1OrD2 as D2;
    if (d2 != null) print("it's d2");
  }
}


void main() async{
  Foo(D2()); // throws exception D2 is not an instance of D1.
  Foo(D1()); // works
}
```

Comment: What exactly does "break" mean here?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer edited the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because the `as` operator in Dart throws if the object is not an instance of the type on the right  (or `null`). It is *not* similar to the `as` operator in C# which evaluates to `null` instead of throwing.

Your code starts with `var d1 = d1OrD2 as D1;` When `d1OrD2` is a `D2` instance, that operation throws.

What you should do instead is:

```
void Foo(Base d1OrD2) {
  if (d1OrD2 is D1) {
    // Static type of d1OrD2 is D1 here, you can call D1 methods on it.
    print("it's d1");
  } else {
    var d2 = d1OrD2 as D2;
    print("it's d2");
  }
}
```

Comment: So in Dart, once you use `is` to test type and it return `true`, the instance being tested is automatically converted to the tested type? Namely, it's better to use `is` than `as` in Dart?

Comment: There is no conversion happening. It's just that static analysis can infer that at runtime the branch can only be reached if the type is `D1` and autocompletion shows proper suggestions. If `d10rD2` is a getter, this won't work anymore as far as I remember, because a getter could return a different value on a subsequent access. Just to demonstrate that this can't be applied broadly.

Comment: Correct. In *some* cases a test like `x is D1` will promote the type of the *variable* `x` to `D1`. It requires that `x` is a local variable with a type that is a super-type of `D1`, and not `dynamic`, and that there are no assignments to `x` in the code guarded by the test.